# meld opens incorrect path to local file

Tags: git, path, macos-catalina, git-config, meld

recently installed meld on my macOS Catalina as mentioned [here](https://yousseb.github.io/meld/). My gitconfig file section that uses this looks like this:

```
[diff]
    tool = meld
[difftool]    
  prompt = false
[difftool "meld"]
  trustExitCode = true
  cmd = open -W -a Meld --args \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

However when I do a `git difftool` on the root of the repository, it cannot seem to find the path to the local file and assumes it is located at '/'. However when I use the GUI explorer I can point meld to the correct location.

I wonder why meld is unable to find the correct path when opened via git.

Comment: a. have you tried dropping the `[difftool "meld"]` section completely from your `.gitconfig` ? git has a built-in default command for `meld`. b. have you, unlike the post you refer to, tried to open `meld` directly without using `open ...` : `cmd = meld \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"` ? (note: I'm not a MacOS user, perhaps there is some obvious reason why `meld` should be started through `open -a meld ...`)

Comment: As a workaround this is how my gitconfig section looks as of now `cmd = open -W -a Meld --args \"$LOCAL\" \"$PWD/$REMOTE\"` . An ugly hack for sure, but it works (for now)

Comment: by the way: what happens if you type `open -W -a Meld --args file1 file2` on the command line ? my guess is the issue is with how `open` works, but I could be wrong